# ASP.net: singleton class, instantiate just once per request?

Tags: asp.net, session, httpwebrequest, singleton, instantiation

I have a class called `UserContext` that tracks the activities of a given user on my website.  It should be a singleton class (just one instance per user). In a Windows Forms application, I'd could write something like this:

```
Class UserContext

    Public Shared Current As New UserContext()

    Private Sub New(appName As String)

    [...]

End Class
```

But on an ASP.net app, this would get shared across all current users.

If this class were only being used within a Page entity I could just store the UserContext instance in a Page variable—it doesn't necessarily need to survive postbacks.  But other entities (that don't know about Page) also call UserContext, and I'd like them all to be given the same instance.

**What can I do to ensure that a class is only instantiated once per *http request* (or per user)?**  Could I use the cache for this?

```
Public Shared Function GetContext() As UserContext
    If HttpContext.Current.Cache("CurrentUserContext") Is Nothing Then HttpContext.Current.Cache("CurrentUserContext") = New UserContext()
    Return HttpContext.Current.Cache("CurrentUserContext")
End Function
```

Might session state be a better option?

Cache and session state both survive postbacks—is there another option that resets with each new request?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.Cache` will be shared among all users. `HttpContext.Current.Session` is per user but persists for subsequent requests.

You need `HttpContext.Current.Items`:

```
Public Shared Function GetContext() As UserContext
    If HttpContext.Current.Items("CurrentUserContext") Is Nothing Then HttpContext.Current.Items("CurrentUserContext") = New UserContext()
    Return HttpContext.Current.Items("CurrentUserContext")
End Function
```

This will ensure a safe per request and per user cache store.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a locking strategy to handle concurrent requests if you are storing the variable for longer than the life of the request. Always assign on your read, and employ double-checked locking to enforce singleton.

```
Private ReadOnly lockObj As New Object()
Private Const CurrentUserContextKey As String = "CurrentUserContext"

Public Function GetContext() As UserContext
    Dim session = HttpContext.Current.Session
    Dim userContext = TryCast(session(CurrentUserContextKey), UserContext)
    If userContext Is Nothing Then
        SyncLock lockObj
            userContext = TryCast(session(CurrentUserContextKey), UserContext)
            If userContext Is Nothing Then
                userContext = New UserContext()
                session(CurrentUserContextKey) = userContext
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End If
    Return userContext
End Function
```